# Why does the term test not match the 'limit calculus trick of convergence' for the infinite series of (k^2 - 3k + 1) / (3k^2 + k - 2)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am new so sorry if my noobness shines through.

In calculus I thought we learned that when faced with polynomial over polynomial like this, because the powers are equal on top and bottom this should **converge** to the ratio of the first coefficients which makes sense because they have the highest impact due to the x^2. Is this only true for limits of functions and not series here?

In an analysis book I am working through, there is a term test that says if a series converges then lim (an) is 0. However this seems contradictory because that implies the series I am working on diverges because the limit is non zero?

Which way of thinking is correct here? Does this series converge to 1/3 or diverge from the term test?

Comment: The sequence of terms converges to $1/3$. The series (i.e. sum) of those terms diverges, which follows since the limit of the terms themselves is not $0$. If the terms did converge to $0$, then the series might or might not converge, depending on the specifics of the terms.

Comment: When discussing a series, there are two sequences to keep in mind.  The sequence of terms and the sequence of partial sums.  You do not say so, but you seem to be describing the situation where the general term is a rational function with numerator and denominator degrees equal to $2$, so you deduce that the limit of the sequence of terms exists and is $1/3$.  Since the sequence of terms does not decrease to zero, the sequence of partial sums increases without bound, so the limit of partial sums does not exist.  If you forget which sequence you are talking about, this can be confusing.

Comment: You are confusing the words "sequence" and "series".  If the **series** $\sum a_n$ converges, then the **sequence** $(a_n)_n$ converges to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\ a_n\ $ is a sequence of real numbers with $\ a_n \not\to 0.\ $ Then $\ \sum\ a_n\ $ does not converge. I prove this result now.

By definition of "not converges to $0",\ \exists \varepsilon>0\ $  such that $\ \vert a_n \vert > \varepsilon\ $ for infinitely many integers $\ n.\ (*)$

Suppose $\ \displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i\right)\ = L\in\mathbb{R}.\ $Then $ \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}\ $  such that $\ \displaystyle \lvert L - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i\right)\ \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\ $ for all $ k\geq N.$

Furthermore, $\ (*)\implies\ $there exists $\ N'>N\ $ such that $\ \vert a_{N'}\vert > \varepsilon.\ $

However, since

$\displaystyle\lvert L - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N'-1} a_i\right)\ \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2},\ $ i.e. $\ L + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} >\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N'-1} a_i\right)\ > L - \frac{\varepsilon}{2},\ $ we must have either$ \ \displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N'} a_i\right)\ =  \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N'-1} a_i \right)+ a_{N'}\ > L + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\ $ or  $ \ \displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N'} a_i\right)\ < L - \frac{\varepsilon}{2},\ $ contradicting the assumption that $\ \displaystyle \lvert L - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i\right)\ \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\ $ for all $ k\geq N.$